# how to do a simple calculate in web.py template

Tags: python, templates, web.py

in `web.py`'s template, I can retrieve number like this:

```
$for item in item_list:
   <td>$item.get("fans_cnt")</td>
```

and this `$item.get("fans_cnt")` will get a number, now I want it divided by 1000, but this won't work:

```
$for item in item_list:
    <td>$item.get("fans_cnt")/1000</td>
```

So, what's the right way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor), under heading Syntax, section *Expression Substitution*:

> Special character $ is used to specify python expressions. Expression can be enclosed in () or {} for explicit grouping.

So:

```
$for item in item_list:
    <td>$(item.get("fans_cnt")/1000)</td>
```

should do what you want.